# Retrieve the FacebookBatchParameter in PostCompleted Event

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using the Facebook C# SDK but writing the application in Visual Basic. Because of this, I'm not able to create the event handler on the fly as shown in the C# examples:

```
fb.GetCompleted += (o, e) => {             };
```

Instead I am doing this:

```
AddHandler fb.GetCompleted , AddressOf HandleGetCompleted
```

The problem with this is I'm not sure how to tell which request I made to the Facebook API in the `HandleGetCompleted` Function. For example `me/home` and `me/accounts` both return a `JsonArray` called `data` but I wouldn't be able to tell whether it was the account data or the news feed data. Is there some way to keep track of the `FacebookBatchParameters` that were used to trigger each event?

Comment: which .net version are you using. if you are using the one that support TPL you can use GetTaskAsync instead else create a new instance of FacebookClient.